# Mixed date formats dd/mm/yyyy and d/m/y in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, date, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with mixed date formats in a  column. Some of it is in the format dd/mm/yyyy and some of it is in the format d/m/y. How can I set the column as datetime by applying the appropriate format depending on the value of the cell?
I am reading from a csv file:

```
DayofWeek,Date
Friday,22/05/2015
Friday,10/2/12
Friday,10/10/14
Friday,21/10/2011
Friday,8/7/11
```

Comment: How is `pd.read_csv('path_to_csv_file', parse_dates=[1], dayfirst=True)`? Or `pd.read_csv('file_with_dates.csv', parse_dates=['Date'], dayfirst=True)`?

Comment: Like wise if the file is already read in you can use pandas datetime  `pd.to_datetime(df.Date, dayfirst=True)`

Comment: Thanks both approaches worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = pd.read_csv('dates.txt', parse_dates=['Date'], dayfirst=True)
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 2 columns):
DayofWeek    5 non-null object
Date         5 non-null datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), object(1)
memory usage: 100.0+ bytes

print(df)

  DayofWeek       Date
0    Friday 2015-05-22
1    Friday 2012-02-10
2    Friday 2014-10-10
3    Friday 2011-10-21
4    Friday 2011-07-08
```

Comment: infer_datetime_format=True option is a more generic solution for date time parsing